# Tibco BW XML parsing mapping Accumulation

Tags: tibco, businessworks

Being new to Tibco BW development I have a scenario which may be easy for you experts to solve/suggest.

I have an XML

```
 <FILES>
 <FILEINFO>
 <NAME>F1<NAME>
 <DESC>D1<DESC>
 </FILEINFO>
 <FILEINFO>
 <NAME>F2<NAME>
 <DESC>D2<DESC>
 </FILEINFO>
 </FILES>
```

---

I want to convert/map/accumulate it into following format.

```
<ALLDATA>
<NAMES>
<NAME>F1</NAME>
<NAME>F2</NAME>
</NAMES>
<DESCRIPTIONS>
<DESCR>D1</DESCR>
<DESCR>D2</DESCR>
</DESCRIPTIONS>
</ALLDATA>
```

I tried to do what I could but to no avail. Could you please let me know how to do it . Best if you can send me a working BW process for the same so that I can understand it better.

Thanks for your help in Advance.
DMEHA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

[image: Process]

I hope this helps.